# Q1 : priority_queue "come before means output last", Q2 : custom compare with sort and priority_queue

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue, custom-compare

Q1

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

i'm looking this webpage and in template parameters section Compare says like this.

> But because the priority queue outputs largest elements first, the
> elements that "come before" are actually output last.

i learned that heap realization like this.

```
parent node : i / 2 
left child node : i * 2 
right child node : i * 2 + 1
```

so if i make max heap then array will made like this.

https://media.vlpt.us/images/emplam27/post/4a05c33e-2caf-4b28-964c-7019c13ff34b/%ED%9E%99%20-%20%EB%B0%B0%EC%97%B4%EB%A1%9C.png

so i can't understand why come before element will output last mean. did i miss something?

Q2

i want to make custom compare object for sort and priority queue. here is my code.

```
struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(vector<int>& l, vector<int>& r) { return r[1] < l[1]; }
};

bool compare(vector<int>& l, vector<int>& r) { return l[0] < r[0]; }

int solution(vector<vector<int>> jobs) {
    sort(jobs.begin(), jobs.end(), compare);
    priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, Compare> jobQueue;
}
```

i was wanted that sort should be ascending, and priority_queue should be min heap to pop least element first. and code work right.

but i feel that code is little unpretty that similar compare were separated.

i want that compare function united to Compare class, but operator() function will be redeclared.

is it possible to unite code?

Comment: @molbdnilo ah, now i see why Q2 compare function work opposite sort and priority_queue. thanks!.
and i'm sorry but is there any way to solve Q2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 is mostly a terminology clash; the ordering relation `a < b` usually says "`a` is ordered before `b`", but in a priority_queue, `a < b` means "`a` has a lower priority than `b`".
So `b` is before `a` in the priority order. (That is, the priority order is the opposite of the ordering relation's order.)

Here is one suggestion regarding Q2; a class template.

```
template<typename T, size_t index>
struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(vector<int>& l, vector<int>& r) { return order(l[index], r[index]); }
    T order;
};

using SortedOrder = Compare<std::less<int>, 0>;
using PriorityOrder = Compare<std::greater<int>, 1>;

int solution(vector<vector<int>> jobs) {
    sort(jobs.begin(), jobs.end(), SortedOrder());
    priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, PriorityOrder> jobQueue;
    return 0;
}
```